# Why even after specifiying min-width 768px the styles of default style.css rendered in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

Okay, This is a bit strange but as I completed my editing for tablet size the stylesheet picked up was of mobile version. 
I have mentioned the media queries like this

```
@media (min-device-width: 768px) {...}
```

I am working in **bootstrap** and not really sure why this is happening. Last time around when I did this I coded for Medium devices first and then went for smaller devices. This time around I coded for mobile version first as per bootsrap's tagline of `MOBILE FIRST`.Then I structured the site accordingly for 768px and above and even refreshed the page several times while doing so until it was completely done.Then suddenly the page rendered the styles of mobile stylesheet which is named STYLE.CSS with no media queries written whatsover in it.
Following a bottom-up approach seems logical too this time, But why the heck is style not working ?

And one more thing, the styling which I did for 768px and above in the stylesheet `sm.css`
applies from 980px onwards which has ofcourse has another stylesheet named `md.css`
Can anyone explain this anamoly..?

I have tried

- adding `!Important` tags on almost all the elements
- Changed my media query to `@media only screen (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {...}`

But all of this in vain.

Can anyone explain this anamoly..?

Update

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">    // DEFAULT
      <link href="css/sm.css" rel="stylesheet">  //@media (min-width: 768px)
      <link href="css/md.css" rel="stylesheet">  //@media (min-width: 980px)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to consider here is that `!Important` tags aren't working. That means that your media query isn't returning true, since `!Important` would have been an override for any styles that were more specific. With that in mind, I would focus on trying different media queries.

It's kind of hard to give specifics without seeing your CSS file, but there are a few things I would try.

- Try using `min-width` instead of `min-device-width`. It may be better to test against the viewport versus testing against the resolution. You'll probably want to use `min-device-width` during production, but it can be useful to use `min-width`, especially during testing.
- Play around with the specific values used in your media query. I've occasionally had to use media queries like `(min-width: 767px)` for devices that were 768px. This may actually be the case, considering the other anomaly you mentioned with your `md.css` file.
- Double check the order in which your media queries are occurring. If two different media queries are returning true, then the browser will go with the last one occurring due to the nature of CSS.